# Create a document of specific structure using pymongo and flask

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

I would like some help with flask, pymongo and some ideas.

What I want to do:

- I have a list:

  ```
  lg=[{'name_dep': name_dep, 'cod_prg': cod_prg, 'name_prg': name_prg,
       'cod_form': cod_form, 'an_s': frm['an_s'], 'serie': serie,
       'nr_s':frm['nr_s'], 'nr_gr': frm['nr_gr'], 'nr_sgr': frm['nr_sgr']}]
  ```

where `frm=mongo.db.colecttion1`

- I want to create a temporary collection of which documents have the structure:

  ```
  { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("576d3494b7e8f8d6d0d7d0e6"),  
      "name_dep" : "name_dep1", 
      "cod_prg" : "cod1", 
      "an_s" : "1", 
      "name_prg" : "name1", 
      "forms" : [
          {
              "nr_gr" : "5", 
              "nr_sgr" : "10", 
              "nr_s" : "150"
          }
          {
              "nr_gr" : "6", 
              "nr_sgr" : "12", 
              "nr_s" : "90"
          }
          {
              "nr_gr" : "2", 
              "nr_sgr" : "4", 
              "nr_s" : "50"
          }
      ], 
      "cod_form" : "1", 
      "serie" : "XX"
  }
  ```

The code for achieving that is:

```
if mongo.db.form_temp:
        mongo.db.form_temp.drop()
    coll_temp=mongo.db.form_temp
    formatie1=lg[0]
    coll_temp.insert({'name_dep':formatie1['name_dep'], 'cod_prg':formatie1['cod_prg'], 'name_prg':formatie1['name_prg'], 'cod_form':formatie1['cod_form'], 'an_s':formatie1['an_s'], 'serie':formatie1['serie'], 'forms':[{'nr_s':formatie1['nr_s'], 'nr_gr':formatie1['nr_gr'], 'nr_sgr':formatie1['nr_sgr']}]})

    for y in range (1, len(lg)-1):
        x=lg[y]
        dep_in_coll=mongo.db.coll_temp.find_one({ '$and': [{'name_dep':x['name_dep']}, {'cod_prg':x['cod_prg']}]})
        if dep_in_coll is None:
            coll_temp.insert({'name_dep':x['name_dep'], 'cod_prg':x['cod_prg'], 'name_prg':x['name_prg'], 'cod_form':x['cod_form'], 'an_s':x['an_s'], 'serie':x['serie'], 'forms':[{'nr_s':x['nr_s'], 'nr_gr':x['nr_gr'], 'nr_sgr':x['nr_sgr']}]})
        else:
            iddoc=dep_in_coll['_id']
            listforms=dep_in_coll['forms']
            listforms.append([{'nr_s':x['nr_s'], 'nr_gr':x['nr_gr'], 'nr_sgr':x['nr_sgr']}])
            dep_in_coll.update({'_id':iddoc}, {'$set' : {'forms': listforms}})
```

What I'doing is to drop the temporary collection if exists and then to create the collection again and insert the first element of the list lg.

Then iterate through the lg list and for each the same values of the pair `name_dep , cod_prg` modify the forms list by adding the fields `nr_s`, `nr_gr`, `nr_sgr` with their values.

My code doesn't run as expected, but inserting the documents in the temp collection, the collection having the same no. of documents as lg list, without modifying the forms list.

Thank you.

Comment: You are updating a key called `formatii`, not a key called `forms`. Could that be your problem?

Comment: It is forms key. I've just made the correction.